# Replacing specific values in a formula without affecting others in Java with Spring boot

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a mathematical formula represented as a string, like this:

**"A+AB+A/B-BB+BC+C"**
I need to replace the values of B and C with new values, let's say X and Y, respectively, without affecting other occurrences of BC in the formula. I'm using Java for this task.

Here's the Java code I have so far:

```
String formula = "A+AB+A/B-BB+BC+C";
String newFormula = formula.replaceAll("B", "X").replaceAll("C", "Y");
```

However, this code replaces all occurrences of 'B' and 'C' in the formula, including the 'BC' term. What I want to achieve is to replace only individual 'B' and 'C' without changing 'BC'. How can I modify this code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place word boundaries around `B` and `C`, i.e. match on `\bB\b` and `\bC\b`:

```java
String newFormula = formula.replaceAll("\\bB\\b", "X")
                           .replaceAll("\\bC\\b", "Y");
```